# Mit Kanonen auf Spatzen schießen: aus welcher Sprache stammt die Wendung?

Tags: etymology, idiom

Auf der Suche nach einer passenden Übersetzung in die englische Sprache für die Redewendung *Mit Kanon auf Spatzen schießen* stieß ich auf folgende Ungereimtheit:

Die passendste Übersetzung ins Englische scheint *to crack a nut with a sledgehammer* zu sein, laut [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mit_Kanonen_auf_Spatzen_schie%C3%9Fen). So ähnlich dann auch das französische Äquivalent: *écraser une mouche avec un marteau*.

Fast wörtlich hingegen die Übersetzung ins italienische, schwedische und niederländische.

[Russen scheinen das für eine einheimische Erfindung zu halten](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100218/to-shoot-out-of-cannon-into-sparrows/100220#100220).

[Redensarten-index nun sagt](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=mit%20Kanonen%20auf%20Spatzen%20schie%C3%9Fen&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou):

> umgangssprachlich; Lateinisch canna (Rohr) hat über ital. cannone (große Röhre) zu Kanone (Geschützrohr) geführt. Diese Übernahme geschah vermutlich zwischen dem 15. und 17. Jahrhundert, als die Kriegstechnik mit französischen und italienischen Ausdrücken versehen war. Der Spatz ist gegenüber dem Geschütz ein denkbar unterlegener Gegner, so dass die Wendung einen starken (und damit erheiternden) Kontrast enthält.
>
> Die Redewendung wurde vermutlich 1872 von dem österreichisch-ungarischen Politiker Graf Gyula Andrássy geprägt, als es im "Kulturkampf" um die Auseinandersetzungen Deutschlands mit der katholischen Kirche ging, in deren Zuge die Jesuitengesetze verabschiedet wurden, die Niederlassungen des Jesuitenordens auf dem Boden des Deutschen Kaiserreichs verbot. Andrássy hielt das für übertrieben. Das "Laibacher Tagblatt" schreibt 1872: "Trügt nicht alles, so dürfte Deutschland sogar nicht lange mehr allein dastehen im Kampfe gegen den Jesuitismus und das angeblich dem Grafen Andrassy zugeschriebene Wort: 'Er denke nicht mit Kanonen auf Spatzen zu schießen', wird wahrscheinlich bald durch die Ereignisse widerlegt sein…"

Stammt diese Redewendung tatsächlich oder wenigstens wahrscheinlich von Andrássy als eigene Neuschöpfung oder wurde das aus einer anderen Sprache übernommen?

Comment: Auf Schwedisch heißt es "mit Kanonen auf Mücken schießen"

Comment: @Beta   Also ungefähr *med kanöner på möcker*?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann ja so ungefähr ;) Genauer: "Skjuta mygg med kanoner".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann War das jetzt ernst gemeint oder ein fiktives Schwedisch? Trolle kommen ja bekanntlich aus der Region ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Hmm ...

'*Das ist doch **unter aller Kanone***' geht tatsächlich zurück auf *sub omni canone*, was jedoch 'unterhalb jeglichen Maßes' bedeutet. Schreibt Kluge. Etym.WB.

Kanonenartige Geschütze gibt es in Europa erst seit dem frühen 14. Jahrhundert; das Wort selber hat sich im deutschsprachigen Raum im 17. Jh. eingebürgert.

Somit nach der Ausschlussmethode: Aus dem Lateinischen stammt die Kanonen-Spatzen-Wendung garantiert nicht.

Grimm führt aus:

η) weitere bildliche redeweisen: spatzen schieszen, tirar' a passeri, met. consumare la polvere e le palle inutilmente. spatzen fangen, pigliar passeri, met. zonzeare, andar' à spasso per otio. Kramer dict. 2, 852a; spatzen unter dem hut tragen, portar passeri sotto 'l cappello, met. non salutar nissuno per via. ebenda (noch jetzt üblich). jetzt besonders auf spatzen mit kanonen schieszen, für einen kleinen zweck grosze zurüstungen treffen, s. Wander 4, 670, 34.

[Bd. 16, Sp. 2003 bis 2007] = http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS33134#XGS33134

Jetzt musst du nur noch in Bd. 33 schauen, von wann "Wander 4, 670, 34" ist.  Der 33. Band ist leider nicht online, aber die (für dich) nächste Bibliothek ist morgen wieder offen. Immerhin. :-)

Cheers!

Comment: [Hier](http://www.zeno.org/Wander-1867/A/Kanone?hl=kanonen) wird für Wander das Jahr 1867 angegeben, aber es gibt eine weitere Referenz auf *Altmann VI, 512; Reinsberg IV, 76.*, was sich auf deas Werk *Die Sprichwörter der Russen, die einen allgemeinen Charakter haben* von 1855 bezieht.